# Set Relations and empty set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How would I formally prove this?

$x \subseteq y \leftrightarrow x-y = \emptyset$, where x,y are sets in universe U

Comment: Please post the work you have completed so far on this proof so that we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context the "$-$" symbol appears to be overloaded as *set difference*; which is more usually represented by the "$\setminus$" symbol.

---

Proof of $~x\subseteq y \to x\setminus y=\emptyset$ follows:

By definition of *set difference:* $~x\setminus y := \{a: a\in x\wedge a\notin y\}~$, and yet by definition of *subset*: $~x\subseteq y~$ iff $~\forall a\in x: a\in y~$.   Ergo: $~x\setminus y=\emptyset~$.

That is to say that: by definition $x\setminus y$ is the set of all elements which are both in $x$ and not in $y$, yet by definition of subset, all elements that are in $x$ are also in $y$,† leading to the conclusion that $x\setminus y$ must be empty.

( † ie: there are *no* elements in $x$ which are not in $y$. )

---

It is left up to you to prove that $x\setminus y=\emptyset \to x\subseteq y$ .